# Javers - Can't track mongo updates inside a document

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, javers

I am trying to keep a track of changes made on specific fields inside a document.
This is my user class. I want to keep a track of any change made in count using Javers.

```
@Document
public class User {

    @Id
    private String userId;
    private String name;
    private int count;
    private Date creationDate = new Date();
    private Map<String, String> userSettings = new HashMap<>();
}
```

I have added the following code to keep a track of whenever a new Object of User is created.

```
@Override public User addNewUser(User user) {
        mongoTemplate.save(user);
        javers.commit("Added", user);
        return user;
    }
```

This is the updateCount method using MongoTemplate:

```
@Override public boolean updateCount(String name) {
        Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("name").is(name));
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("count").gt(0));
        Update update = new Update();
        update.inc("count", -1);
        return Objects
            .requireNonNull(reactiveMongoTemplate.updateFirst(query, update, User.class).block())
            .getModifiedCount() == 1;
    }
```

Now what I want to track is to commit some kind of change at the end of updateCount method call.
But these changes can't be committed unless I have an entity object. How do I go about this?

Comment: I don't understand your question, try to rephrase it in the context of Javers API

Comment: `javers.commit("AUTHOR", <entity>)`

Basically, what I am trying to do is performing an update inside mongodb, but I cannot commit the same through Javers since it requires an entity for me to commit. But here, since the update is through a MongoTemplate, it only requires the identifier to update the data (I don't have an entity at this point in time). So how do I keep track of update queries?

Answer (score 0):

Javers is the object auditing framework, you can't track changed made by direct db updates in Javers. All you can do is to take some Java object (an entity), and call `javers.commit()` on it